# Parse XML to Java

Tags: java, xml, parsing

```
<Question>
<Questions ID="1">
<English> What is water in French? </English>
<Answer> Eau </Answer>
</Questions>
</Question>
```

I have the above XML file for example (question.xml), and I'll like to print the contents in "English" then request user input, then compare that to the "Answer". How do I do that in Java

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/sax/index.html

Comment: Raul's response is correct.  You could parse the XML, store the values in a DB or in memory and write a servlet and some logic to compare the user's response to what you have in the database.  It's a little bit of work, but not terribly complicated.  Probably a decent first project in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy way could be to read all your XML and store your English and Answer values, after parsing, you can request user input.

If you want to request input as you parse, you could write a multi-threaded program, in which one thread parses the XML and the other requests user input, synchronizing both threads with locks, however this would be difficult to implement and risky to detect and catch bugs...

Answer (score 1):

There are several java api for XML Parsing

- [SAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_API_for_XML)
- [DOM](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/)
- StAX
- TrAX

In your case DOM parser is best. Use DOM parser link to quick guide to learn